# Magento 2 : how to create customer using REST API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I want to create customer using REST API in magento2. I am following [this swagger link](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/#/) , but only method is given in this. How to pass parameters of customer in REST API?

Help me in this.

Comment: Are you want to create simple customer using API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Create New Customer**

```
    $userData = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "admin123");
    $ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

    $token = curl_exec($ch);


    $customerData = [
        'customer' => [
            "email" => "user@example.com",
            "firstname" => "John",
            "lastname" => "Doe",
            "storeId" => 1,
            "websiteId" => 1
        ],
        "password" => "Demo1234"
    ];

    $ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/customers");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    $result = json_decode($result, 1);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

**For Update Customer**

```
$customerData = [
    'customer' => [
        'id' => 10,
        "email" => "user@example.com",
        "firstname" => "John2",
        "lastname" => "Doe2",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1
    ],
    "password" => "Demo1234"
];

$ch = curl_init("http://magento213/index.php/rest/V1/customers/10");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);
```

[API LIST](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/list.html)

Comment: How can I post an profile image ?.. please check my question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186036/sign-up-with-avatar-rest-api-validation-error-magento-2?noredirect=1#comment257219_186036

Comment: Life saving code.I was breaking my head against this for two days. Thanks, _/\_ _/\_ _/\_ _/\_ _/\_ _/\_

Comment: with addresses?

Comment: Is it possible to create the customer without a password? And either have the password auto generated or email the customer to create their password

Answer (score 3):

Adding more to the @BornCoder answer, if you want to add addresses as well for the new customer, you can find this example helpful. Also setting custom customer attribute `woo_customer_id` in the example.

```
$customerData = [
    'customer' => [
        "email" => "abc@xyz.com",
        "firstname" => "ABC",
        "lastname" => "XYZ",
        "createdAt" => "4/26/2017  2:31:22 PM",
        "storeId" => 1,
        "websiteId" => 1,
        "groupId" => 1,
        "customAttributes" => [
            [
                "attributeCode" => "woo_customer_id",
                "value" => "444445"
            ]
        ],
        "addresses" => [
            [
                "firstname" => "ABC",
                "lastname" => "XYZ",
                "countryId" => "MY",
                "street" => [
                    "No 545 Jalan balau 27/13",
                    "sinar link Taman rinting"
                ],
                "company" => "Mahnazfood",
                "telephone" => "04040404040404",
                "fax" => "01010101101010101",
                "postcode" => "81750",
                "city" => "Masai",
                "defaultBilling" => true
            ],
            [
                "firstname" => "ABC",
                "lastname" => "XYZ",
                "countryId" => "MY",
                "street" => [
                    "Colony#3 Block#126/F",
                    "Address 2 "
                ],
                "company" => "Ashtech",
                "telephone" => "090078601",
                "fax" => "00000000000000",
                "postcode" => "45000",
                "city" => "Lahore",
                "defaultShipping" => true
            ]
        ]
    ],
    "password" => "Demo12345"
];

/*
 * Post customer in magento
 */
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost/smagemahnaz/index.php/rest/V1/customers");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($customerData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
    array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($_COOKIE["magento_token"]))
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);

$result = json_decode($result, 1);
echo '<pre>';print_r($result); echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Endpoint: POST /rest/default/V1/customers

Scope: default store view

Final Url: http://www.mag2.loc/rest/default/V1/customers

Headers:Content-Type: application/json

Authorization: Bearer <admin_token>

plz check screen shot :

[image] [image]

Payload:

```
{
   "customer" : {
      "lastname" : "Doe",
      "firstname" : "Jane",
      "email" : "jdoe@example.com",
      "addresses" : [
         {
            "defaultBilling" : true,
            "defaultShipping" : true,
            "firstname" : "Jane",
            "lastname" : "Doe",
            "region" : {
               "regionCode" : "NY",
               "regionId" : 43,
               "region" : "New York"
            },
            "countryId" : "US",
            "postcode" : "11501",
            "city" : "Mineola",
            "street" : [
               "160 1st St."
            ],
            "telephone" : "516-555-1111"
         }
      ]
   },
   "password" : "Password1"
}
Response:

The customer id is 2.

{
    "id": 2,
    "group_id": 1,
    "default_billing": "2",
    "default_shipping": "2",
    "created_at": "2020-07-22 23:12:47",
    "updated_at": "2020-07-22 23:13:15",
    "created_in": "Default Store View",
    "email": "jdoe@example.com",
    "firstname": "Jane",
    "lastname": "Doe",
    "store_id": 1,
    "website_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "customer_id": 2,
            "region": {
                "region_code": "NY",
                "region": "New York",
                "region_id": 43
            },
            "region_id": 43,
            "country_id": "US",
            "street": [
                "160 1st St."
            ],
            "telephone": "516-555-1111",
            "postcode": "11501",
            "city": "Mineola",
            "firstname": "Jane",
            "lastname": "Doe",
            "default_shipping": true,
            "default_billing": true
        }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
        "is_subscribed": false
    }
}
```