# Magento 2 Customer Import using API

Tags: magento2, customer, api, import

I've been given a csv of customers that I need to import using the Magento 2 API, and i've never created an API before. Can anyone point me in the right direction a starting point, or an example of how the import API would look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example code to add or update customer using REST API, please refer following thread.

[Magento 2 : how to create customer using REST API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154429/magento-2-how-to-create-customer-using-rest-api)