# What is the best way to import/create products , customers and orders in magento 2.x

Tags: magento2, rest-api, importexport, soap-api-v2

I have a `third party Soap API`, I have to create products, customers, orders and other related data in Magento 2.x. `periodically like every 24 hours.`

There are around 15k products and orders.

What i am planning is to 
 Create a new extension and use Magento 2 APIs to do so
something like this [create a customer using api](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154429/magento-2-how-to-create-customer-using-rest-api)

Is there any other approach for the same. What will be the best way to do so?

If possible please share any helpful link or tutorial for the same.

Comment: Do you need data for testing?

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. No i have third party api for data, before i start to do this i am planning to have the best approach for this situation

Comment: You can create this data using Magento commands.

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. please share any link to do this as i never did