# custom api to create customer in Magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api

I have created custom api to create/update customer in magento2.

This is my webapi.xml file

```
 <route url="/V1/customer/createUpdate" method="POST">
    <service class="[Vendor]\[Module]\Api\CustomCustomerInterface" method="createUpdate"/>
    <resources>
        <resource ref="anonymous"/>
    </resources>
</route>
```

Here is my [Vendor]/[Module]/Api/CustomCustomerInterface.php

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Api;

interface CustomCustomerInterface
{

/**
 * POST for attribute api
 * @param mixed $param
 * @return array
 */

public function createUpdate($params);

}
```

Here is the code of [Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml

```
<preference for="[Vendor]\[Module]\Api\CustomCustomerInterface"
            type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\createUpdate" />
```

Below is the code of [Vendor]/[Module]/Model/createUpdate.php

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model;
use [Vendor]\[Module]\Api\CustomCustomerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface;

class CreateUpdate implements CustomCustomerInterface
{   
protected $_storeManager;
protected $customerRepository;
protected $accountManagement;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    AccountManagementInterface $accountManagement,
    \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository

) {
    $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->accountManagement = $accountManagement;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function createUpdate($params) {
    $resultArr = array();
    $paramArr = array();
    $result =  json_encode($params);
    $resultSet = json_decode($result,true);

    $customer = $this->accountManagement->createAccount($customer, 
  $password, $redirectUrl);

    }

}
```

Below is my json Request

```
 {
  "params": {
  "Entity_Type": "CreateUpdate_Customer",
  "Entity_Attributes": {
  "Enabled": "No",
  "Phone_No": "123456789",
  "Magento_User_Type": " ",
  "Magento_Customer_ID": "0",
  "Magento_Address_ID": "0",     
  "Mobile_Phone_No": "",
  "First_name": "Test",
  "Middle_name": "",
  "Lastname": "Test",
  "EMail": "test@test.com",
  "Registration_date": "",    
  "Password": ""        
   }
  }
}
```

Yes i seen, by this link we can create customer,

[Magento 2 : how to create customer using REST API?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154429/magento-2-how-to-create-customer-using-rest-api)

I am looking for someone help how this can be done using custom api, as per the code i used in my module.

I need to create customer with some custom attributes also. Please anyone help me on this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch in your functions : in your `CustomCustomerInterface` you declare a function `createUpdate` but in your `createUpdate.php` you only have a function `charityUpdate`.

Be sure to have the same name as the interface. So your function should be like this :

```
public function createUpdate($params) {
 $resultArr = array();
 $paramArr = array();
 $result =  json_encode($params);
 $resultSet = json_decode($result,true);

 $customer = $this->accountManagement->createAccount($customer, 
 $password, $redirectUrl);

}
```

Then you don't use the createAccount function as a good way.

You should do something like this :

```
public function createUpdate($params) {
 $resultArr = array();
 $paramArr = array();
 $result =  json_encode($params);
 $resultSet = json_decode($result,true);

 /** @var \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterfaceFactory */
 $this->customerFactory->create()
        ->setEmail($resultSet['params']['EMail'])
        ->setFirstname($resultSet['params']['First_name']);
 /** and the same for all parameters ..... */

 $customerData = $this->accountManagement
 ->createAccount(
   $newCustomerEntity,
   $resultSet['params']['password'],
   $redirectUrl
 );
}
```

The 3 first lines of your functions are useless for me, you can remove it and if it's only an array, you can remove the json_decode and use the var $params directly.

Comment: yes, i have updated my question,

Comment: @jafarpinjar Answer updated

Comment: can you please update me clear code, because i am confused with this line
$redirectUrl, where you have declared that variable?

Comment: It's a variable you used in the code. So find why you insert it.