# Magento 2 - How to register New Customer from REST API

Tags: magento2, customer, rest-api, register

I am new to REST Api, I am working on to create customer account via using Rest API but struggling with one error which I am trying to find I authorized account properly but when I try to create new account It gives me an error

**First Error**

```
{ "message": "%fieldName is a required field.",
"parameters": {
    "fieldName": "customer"
},
```

**Second Error (After adding Customer Param)**

```
"message": "Please enter a customer email.",
```

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. I tried to use email param but its not working. Can anyone help me with this.

Software use: Postman
Resource: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/tutorials/orders/order-create-customer.html

Comment: check with https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154429/magento-2-how-to-create-customer-using-rest-api this.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1:**
Get authentication key api :

URL - http://example.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

METHOD - POST

BODY :

```
{"username":"adminusername", "password":"adminpassword"}
```

**Step 2 :**
Call customer registration api :
URL - http://example.com/rest/V1/customers

METHOD : POST

HEADER :

```
Authorization: Bearer key
```

BODY :

```
{
  "customer": {
    "id": 0,
    "group_id": 0,
    "default_billing": "string",
    "default_shipping": "string",
    "confirmation": "string",
    "created_at": "string",
    "updated_at": "string",
    "created_in": "string",
    "dob": "string",
    "email": "string",
    "firstname": "string",
    "lastname": "string",
    "middlename": "string",
    "prefix": "string",
    "suffix": "string",
    "gender": 0,
    "store_id": 0,
    "taxvat": "string",
    "website_id": 0,
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "customer_id": 0,
        "region": {
          "region_code": "string",
          "region": "string",
          "region_id": 0,
          "extension_attributes": {}
        },
        "region_id": 0,
        "country_id": "string",
        "street": [
          "string"
        ],
        "company": "string",
        "telephone": "string",
        "fax": "string",
        "postcode": "string",
        "city": "string",
        "firstname": "string",
        "lastname": "string",
        "middlename": "string",
        "prefix": "string",
        "suffix": "string",
        "vat_id": "string",
        "default_shipping": true,
        "default_billing": true,
        "extension_attributes": {},
        "custom_attributes": [
          {
            "attribute_code": "string",
            "value": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "disable_auto_group_change": 0,
    "extension_attributes": {
      "company_attributes": {
        "customer_id": 0,
        "company_id": 0,
        "job_title": "string",
        "status": 0,
        "telephone": "string",
        "extension_attributes": {}
      },
      "is_subscribed": true,
      "amazon_id": "string",
      "vertex_customer_code": "string"
    },
    "custom_attributes": [
      {
        "attribute_code": "string",
        "value": "string"
      }
    ]
  },
  "password": "string",
  "redirectUrl": "string"
}
```

Comment: in magento 2.4 after I create new customer and try to login I get 401 unauthorized. If I try to sign in via website I can't. Any ideea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
In body you've to sent data like the following below.
{
  "customer": {
    "email": "abc@testmail.com",
    "firstname": "your first name",
    "lastname": "your last name",
    "store_id": 1,
    "addresses": [
      {
         "firstname": "your first name",
          "lastname": "your last name",
         "city": "DElhi",
          "street": [
          "117/38"
        ],
        "telephone": "99999999999",
        "country_id": "SA"
      }]
  },
  "password": "admin@123"
}
```